# How to download part of a video?

Tags: video, download, file-download

The total runtime of video clip x is 46m:15s.

All I need is the final scene; ~25 seconds towards the very end of the clip (45m:14s→45m:39s).

Rather than downloading the entire video; how could I download only the part that I need?

The final ~61 seconds would also be acceptable; right to the end - including superfluous final credits. (45m:14s→46m:15s).

Answer (score -1):

- Visit ClipConverter.cc
- Paste the Video link (YouTube, Vimeo,
  DailyMotion or other)
- Then Select the Quality of video you want to
  download (1080p,720p,480p)
- Select the Desired Video Format
  (MP4,3GP,AVI,MOV)
- Now un-check the "Start of video" and enter the time from were you want the video.
- un-check the "End of Video" if you do not want the video till the end and enter your desired time for the end. Click on "Start" button.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will this work with videos purchased through official content providers (Apple iTunes, Google Play, etc.)? I would prefer a local CLI method, but this does seem to have a bunch of relevant features.